# Active Directory The specified account name is already a member of the group

Tags: puppet

I am using puppet version 3.4.2 when adding a domain user to a local user group I get the following Errors

> Active Directory The specified account name is already a member of the group

And

> change from Domain Users,Example-Service Accounts to Administrators,Domain Users,Example-Service Accounts failed: (in OLE method `Add': ) OLE error code:80070562 in Active Directory The specified account name is already a member of the group

The Code is

```
             user { 'remote-user':
                    name => $remoteUser,    
                    ensure => present,
                    groups => "Administrators"
            }
```

> $remoteUser is from hiera { "remoteUser" : "Domain\\example-service"}

According to this ticket https://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/17031 This issue should be fixed, can anyone see what I have missed.

Comment: Is the agent version sure to be above `3.4` as well?

Comment: I tried it on a puppet agent with version 3.4.3 and 3.5.1